# How to Make a graph with 2 data sets plotted?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

as of right now I am trying to create a graph, which is fine until I try to add a third column of data on my .csv file.

So essentially I am taking pressure-area isotherms, and what I have been tasked with is to make a pressure, area graph, which I achieved (woot!)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

 x, y = np.loadtxt("Example.csv", delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Area-mm^2')
plt.ylabel('Pressure mN/m')

plt.title('Pressure-Area Isotherm\nKibron')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

this is what I got, what I need to do now is to also put the average pixel value of some photos I took into the graph so that I can positively correlate the inverse relation between area and pressure/light intensity.

My.csv (excel file) has three columns if it is not possible to do both of these at the same time could someone show me a way to only pick 2 of the three columns to put on the graph? I.E pressure/area, pressure/pixel values , or area/pixel values. I assume it would involve assigning each column a number(n) and have the pyplot graph "n" vs "n" 
Edit: I would also like for their to be a second scale so that the overall graph doesn't look wonky . again thanks for the help!

|1st is area |  then pressure| and average pixel value|

Comment: To get all three columns, just use 

`area, pressure, pixel = np.loadtxt("Example.csv", delimiter=",", unpack=True")`

Then, you can plot them independently:
`plt.plot(area, pressure)`
`plt.plot(area, pixel)`
To plot on two separate axes, see this example: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: You are absolutely the best! I now have a beautiful graph! thanks a bunch jeff!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and create overlaying plots:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open('filename.csv') as f:
   headers = iter(['area', 'pressure', 'pixel'])
   data = {next(headers):list(map(float, b)) for _, *b in zip(*csv.reader(f))}

labels = ['pressure/area', 'pressure/pixel', 'area/pixel']
for i in labels:
  num, denom = i.split('/')
  plt.plot(data[num], data[denom], label = i)

plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```